# jQuery UI - Draggable items in overflow-y:scroll container

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a webpage where I have items on the right which are draggable into columns on the left.  Works great, except I want to set a fixed height or max-height on the items container on the right, with overflow-y:scroll applied.  When I try to do this, the items drag under the target column instead of on top as it should.  If I take the overflow property off the item container div, it works correctly.

Can someone point out where I'm going wrong?  How can I get a scrollable draggable list?

JS Fiddle HERE to show what I mean...
https://jsfiddle.net/bvxxetot/

Here is the javascript code I'm using to init the draggable/droppable areas

**HTML**

```
<div id="tmpl-view-builder-container">

  <div id="tmpl-view-preview-container">
    <div class="droppable">


    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="tmpl-view-legend-container">
    <h3>Available Fields</h3>
    <div id="tmpl-view-legend-item-container">    
        <ul>
          <li>Field 1</li>
          <li>Field 2</li>
          <li>Field 3</li>
          <li>Field 4</li>
          <li>Field 5</li>
          <li>Field 6</li>
          <li>Field 7</li>
          <li>Field 8</li>
          <li>Field 9</li>
          <li>Field 10</li>
      </ul>
    </div>      
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.droppable { border:1px dashed #000000; width:75%; float:left; height:400px;}

#tmpl-view-legend-container {
  position:absolute;
  right:20px;
  top:0px;
  height:400px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}

#tmpl-view-legend-container ul { list-style-type:none; padding:0; }
#tmpl-view-legend-container ul li { background:#CCCCCC; margin-bottom:10px; padding:7px 10px; cursor:pointer; }
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $('.droppable').droppable({
            accept:'#tmpl-view-legend-item-container li',
        hoverClass: 'hovered',
        drop: testDropFunction
    });

    $('#tmpl-view-legend-item-container li').draggable({
            stack: '#tmpl-view-legend-items li',
        cursor: 'move',
        revert: true,
        appendTo: 'body'
    });
});


function testDropFunction(event, ui) {
    alert('Testing!');
}
```

thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get this functionality using the `helper: 'clone'`, however you will need to add some code to fix a few things.

In the draggable constructor:

```
    helper: 'clone',
    start: function(e, ui) {
        ui.helper.width($(this).width());
        $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
        $(this).css('visibility', '');
    }
```

In the CSS:

```
li.ui-draggable.ui-draggable-handle.ui-draggable-dragging { list-style-type:none; background:#CCCCCC; margin-bottom:10px; padding:7px 10px; cursor:pointer; }
```

Here is a working jsfiddle, based on your code:
https://jsfiddle.net/ahx7urbk/